# How do I know what options are available as 3rd argument of ListMapper->add() in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How do I know what options are available as 3rd argument of `ListMapper->add()` in SonataAdminBundle. (Same with `DatagridMapper->add()` and `FormMapper->add()`).

You says there is a link with options http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#options

but there are also a few here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#visual-configuration

How do I know if there are more options available? Perfectly if someone point how to discover that from Sonata code (maybe ListMapper class).

Because f.e. I want to reduce size of text in cell if it's too large, and I don't know if I can use some 3rd argument option or I need to override template.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#options

Comment: ok, that was easy. What about 3rd argument of `FormMapper->add()` ? How do I know that I can use f.e. `'read_only' => true`. As I accidentally found that somewhere but not in documentation.

Comment: `DatagridMapper->add()` http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#filters

Comment: `FormMapper->add()`, `options` depends of your field type http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html

Comment: More options for `ListMapper->add()` http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/field_types.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that options are stored in a **native PHP array** and used *"on-the-fly"* by templates, DoctrineORM bundle, etc... so there is no simple way to find an exhaustive list of all of them.

However, I found a solution to list **almost** all options for the **ListMapper** (some are from the **DatagridMapper**, but it is really difficult to differenciate them).

Here they are:

```
_sort_order
admin_code
ajax_hidden
association_mapping
code
editable
field_mapping
field_name
field_options
field_type
format
global_search
header_class
header_style
identifier
label
mapping_type
name
operator_options
operator_type
options
parameters
parent_association_mappings
route
route.name
route.parameters
row_align
sort_field_mapping
sort_parent_association_mappings
sortable
timezone
translation_domain
virtual_field
```

---

To get this list, I had the idea to make the function **SonataAdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription::getOptions()** returns a custom array object that logs every call to *isset*, *unset*, getters and setters (with brackets operator). I also logs **SonataAdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription::getOption($name, $default = null)** calls.

Code related:

- *TestBundle\ArrayTest*

  ```
  namespace TestBundle;

  class ArrayTest implements \ArrayAccess
  {
      private $container = array();
      private $previousOffset;

      public function __construct($array, $previousOffset = null) {
          $this->container = $array;
          $this->previousOffset = $previousOffset;
      }

      public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
          if (is_null($offset)) {
              $this->container[] = $value;
          } else {
              $this->dump($offset);
              $this->container[$offset] = $value;
          }
      }

      public function offsetExists($offset) {
          $this->dump($offset);
          return isset($this->container[$offset]);
      }

      public function offsetUnset($offset) {
          $this->dump($offset);
          unset($this->container[$offset]);
      }

      public function offsetGet($offset) {
          $this->dump($offset);
          if (isset($this->container[$offset])) {
              if (is_array($this->container[$offset])) {
                  $newOffset = ($this->previousOffset ?: '').$offset.'.';

                  if ($newOffset === 'route.parameter.') { // because of Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin::generateObjectUrl()
                      return $this->container[$offset];
                  }
                  return new ArrayTest($this->container[$offset], $newOffset);
              }

              return $this->container[$offset];
          }
          return null;
      }

      private function dump($offset)
      {
          $offset = ($this->previousOffset ?: '').$offset;
          file_put_contents("/tmp/toto.txt", $offset."\n", FILE_APPEND);
      }
  }
  ```
- *SonataAdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription::getOption($name, $default = null)*

  ```
  public function getOption($name, $default = null)
  {
      file_put_contents("/tmp/toto.txt", $name."\n", FILE_APPEND);
      return isset($this->options[$name]) ? $this->options[$name] : $default;
  }
  ```
- *SonataAdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription::getOptions()*

  New function's prototype : *getOptions($fakeArray = true)*

  ```
  public function getOptions($fakeArray = true)
  {
      if ($fakeArray) {
          return new \TestBundle\ArrayTest($this->options);
      }

      return $this->options;
  }
  ```
- *Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Builder\DatagridBuilder::addFilter(DatagridInterface $datagrid, $type, FieldDescriptionInterface $fieldDescription, AdminInterface $admin)*

  Line 129 :

  ```
  $filter = $this->filterFactory->create($fieldDescription->getName(), $type, $fieldDescription->getOptions());
  ```

  to

  ```
  $filter = $this->filterFactory->create($fieldDescription->getName(), $type, $fieldDescription->getOptions(false));
  ```

Then, display a list on sonata admin, and run `cat /tmp/toto.txt | sort -u` to get the list above.

To get this list of options, I displayed the admin's list of *SonataUserBundle*. You may find more options displaying an other admin list (which uses other templates for example).

---

**N.B.**: I ran this on a clean install of *Symfony 2.8.11*, *SonataAdminBundle 3.8.0*, *SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle 3.1.0* and *SonataUserBundle 3.0.1*.

Comment: bounty awarded, great job!

Answer (score 1):

After **some search in Sonata Bundle code**, *not in documentation* !
I think you have this options:

1. type
2. template
3. help
4. placeholder
5. link_parameters

check in : **Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\BaseFieldDescription::setOptions(array $options)**

You can do all at once like this:

```
  ->add('_action','actions',array(
                                  'actions'=>array(
                                         'view'=>array(),
                                         'edit'=>array(),
                                         'delete'=>array()
                                         )
                                  )
        )
```

We don't use anymore SonataAdmin, is better with my own controllers that fill desires of the project.

A solution for your needs is **to use a template with some twig**:

```
 ->add('first_name', null,array(
       'template'=>'AppBundle:User:_partial_with_some_template.html.twig',)
       )
```

I hope this will help you ! :)
*Have fun !*